# Defining hard links in puppet

Tags: puppet, chroot

Is there a way to define hardlinks inside puppet manifest?

It seems file type can only define symbolic links, but I need it to be hard links in order to make some of my chrooted applications to work. For example, I need to hardlink

```
/etc/hosts -> $chroot/etc/hosts
/etc/resolvf.com -> $chroot/etc/resolv.conf
```

and so on.

What can be the simplest way to archive that?

Update: thanks, I've ended with following defines:

```
define hardlinkdir(source=$name, target) {                                                                                                                   
    exec {                                                                                                                                                   
        "hardlinkdir-$name":                                                                                                                                 
            command => "cp -r --link $target $source",                                                                                                       
            path    => "/usr/bin:/bin",                                                                                                                      
            creates => $source;                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                            

define hardlink(source=$name, target) {                                                                                                                      
    exec {                                                                                                                                                   
        "hardlink-$name":                                                                                                                                    
            command => "ln --force $target $source",                                                                                                         
            path    => "/usr/bin:/bin",                                                                                                                      
            unless  => "test $source -ef $target";                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                        
}
```

Sure, they are not perfect, but they does the job and it's everything I need.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use also the statement "exec" if you can't find any other way.

```
exec { "hardlink1":
    command => "ln target source",
    path    => "/usr/local/bin:/bin",
    creates => "yourhardlink"
}
```

Comment: Use `creates` instead of `unless`.

Comment: Hmm, I think unless can be better, I'll try to check if source & target are really same files.

Comment: @rvs `ls -i` provides the inode number of the file as the first column. Two hard links pointing at the same file on the same filesystem will have the same inode number. You could write up a module to test that.

Comment: They should really support this on the `file` resource IMO.

Answer (score 2):

works for me perfect this..

```
define hardlink($source=$name, $target) {                                                                                                                      
    exec {                                                                                                                                                   
        "hardlink-$name":                                                                                                                                    
            command => "ln -P --force $source $target",                                                                                                         
            path    => "/usr/bin:/bin",                                                                                                                      
            unless  => "test $source -ef $target";                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also fairly trivial to just pipe out the same file to multiple locations with Puppet, as an example:

```
  file { [ "/etc/named.conf", "/var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf" ]:
    mode    => 640,
    owner   => root,
    group   => named,
    ensure  => present,
    require => [ Package['bind'], Package['bind-chroot'], ],
    source  => "puppet:///modules/named/named.conf",
  }
```